Android Cordova gray splash screen after custom one
gif of the problem
My android cordova app has two slash screens, one is the white one with icon (custom) another is the gray one, google play console said i have two, and depending on the phone, the duration of the gray one is not noticeable, but in another, the white one goes away and the gray stays for too long.
How can I remove the gray one? I tried a lot of tutorials, but to no avail.
Here is my config.xml:
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="nikkoin.sejaveloz" version="1.9.31" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>Seja Veloz</name>
    <description>Seja mais rapido que um gato nesse jogo de digitação e veja quantas palavras você consegue antes que o tempo acabe!</description>
    <author email="" href="">
        
    </author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-network-information" source="npm" />


    <platform name="android">
        <preference name="Orientation" value="portrait" />
        <preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="true" />
        <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="2700" />
        <preference name="SplashMaintainAspectRatio" value="true" />
        <preference name="AndroidWindowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon" value="res/screen/android/splashicon.xml" />
        <preference name="AndroidWindowSplashScreenBackground" value="#ffffff" />

        <!-- Define o ícone para Android com diferentes densidades -->
        <icon src="www/img/icons/iconesv_idpi.png" density="ldpi" />
        <icon src="www/img/icons/iconesv_mdpi.png" density="mdpi" />
        <icon src="www/img/icons/iconesv_hdpi.png" density="hdpi" />
        <icon src="www/img/icons/iconesv_xhdpi.png" density="xhdpi" />
        <icon src="www/img/icons/iconesv_xxhdpi.png" density="xxhdpi" />
        <icon src="www/img/icons/iconesv_xxxhdpi.png" density="xxxhdpi" />

    </platform>
   
</widget>

I installed the cordova plugin for the splash screen, it lets me add the custom splash screen. Doesn't remove the default one.
